# Where can I find Glassfish logs on Windows 7?

Tags: glassfish

I can't find the Glassfish logs on windows 7.  I would've expected a `/glassfish/logs` folder, but having searched the glassfish directory I don't see them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's inside `/glassfish/domains/[domainname]/logs` where `[domainname]` is the server domain name, which defaults to `domain1`.

Comment: There's nothing inside my domains folder :-\  The URL my testing takes me to is `localhost:8080/ProjectName`

Comment: So you're running it from inside an IDE? Check the IDE's logs instead.

Comment: Hrmm... I'd be very interested to see how to run it outside of an IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Webnet are you running Glassfish from Netbeans?

I had the same problem expecting to find glassfish logs in `C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs`

I ended up finding them here:

```
D:\Users\myusername\.netbeans\7.0\config\GF3\domain1\logs
```

I installed glassfish along with netbeans and run it from within that ide.  So it looks like because I am running within Netbeans it redirects the logs to that location.

Answer (score 0):

If virtualization is being performed, try:
C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\glassfish\logs

Comment: :-\ nothing there.  I've looked into the