# send mail and attachment file using jsp

Tags: java, jsp, email

I want to send email using jsp. 
I have develop this small code to send email. 
I have added all require library like
java mail API and JAF. But still it is not working. 
I don't know whats going wrong in this.
it shows me Error: unable to send message.

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.mail.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*"%> 
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %> 
<% String result; 
   String to = "kudale.ashish1992@gmail.com"; 
   String from = "kudale.ashish1992@yahoo.com"; 
   String host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"; 
   Properties properties = System.getProperties(); 
   properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host); 
   properties.setProperty("mail.user", "Username");
   properties.setProperty("mail.password", "Paasword");
   //String to = request.getParameter("to"); 
   //String from = request.getParameter("from");
   String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
   String messageText = request.getParameter("body");
   Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties); 
   try{ 
       MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
       message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from)); 
       message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));  
       BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
       messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body"); 
       Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 
       multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
       messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
       String filename = "file.txt"; 
       DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
       messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
       messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 
       multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);   
       message.setContent(multipart ); 
       Transport.send(message); 
       String title = "Send Email"; 
       result = "Sent message successfully...."; 
    }
    catch (MessagingException mex) { 
       mex.printStackTrace(); 
       result = "Error: unable to send message...."; 
   }
 %> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Send email</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<center> <h1>Send Attachement Email using JSP</h1> </center> 
<p align="center"> 
<% out.println("Result: " + result + "\n"); %> 
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stack trace please. it might be issue with your smtp port. It might not be open.

Comment: still not working i opened smtp port 25.

Comment: Did you try `smtp.mail.yahoo.com` as host? as you are sending from yahoo mail

Comment: did you get mail. I just tried and it showed me message sent successfully . no change in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this on my machine two errors I got.

First, You misspelled `properties` here

```
roperties.setProperty("mail.password", "Paasword");
```

Second, Access is denied error for `file.txt`. I managed to give a path to it and it worked.

**RESULT : It showed me message sent successfully.**

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.mail.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*"%> 
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %> 
<% String result; 
   String to = "kudale.ashish1992@gmail.com"; 
   String from = "kudale.ashish1992@yahoo.com"; 
   String host = "localhost"; 
   Properties properties = System.getProperties(); 
   properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host); 
   properties.setProperty("mail.user", "Username");
   properties.setProperty("mail.password", "Paasword");
   //String to = request.getParameter("to"); 
   //String from = request.getParameter("from");
   String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
   String messageText = request.getParameter("body");
   Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties); 
   try{ 
       MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
       message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from)); 
       message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));  
       BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
       messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body"); 
       Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 
       multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
       messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
       String filename = "file.txt"; 
       DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
       messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
       messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 
       multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);   
       message.setContent(multipart ); 
       Transport.send(message); 
       String title = "Send Email"; 
       result = "Sent message successfully...."; 
    }
    catch (MessagingException mex) { 
       mex.printStackTrace(); 
       result = "Error: unable to send message...."; 
   }
 %> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Send email</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<center> <h1>Send Attachement Email using JSP</h1> </center> 
<p align="center"> 
<% out.println("Result: " + result + "\n"); %> 
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still not working. I have added full extracted folder of javamail API, and JAF. should I only add jar files.

Comment: have you got mail ? Its time now to share stack trace.

Comment: You need to add mail.jar and activation.jar files in your CLASSPATH. All the jar files from Java Email API package and JAF package ara available in CLASSPATH.

Comment: not working add library propery. enable smtp port, enble TLS, changed my host to **smtp.mail.yahoo.com**. still not woking

Comment: Share stack trace . how to see it ? What applicaton server are you using. Tomcat,jboss. which one?

Comment: GlassFish Sever. what is stack trace? and how to share that?

Comment: stack trace are like server logs. which identifies what kind of exception it is throwing.

Comment: Refer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468608/where-can-i-find-glassfish-logs-on-windows-7,....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835913/location-of-glassfish-server-logs

Comment: I read above links. but I don't know how to over come this issue. `C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs` the logs folder is empty.

Comment: I found server.logs file inside `\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\config\GF3\domain1\logs` it shows me error IOException: Access is denied. and some lines below that starts with at java.io..., at org.apache.., at com.sun.. and many more. what to do now.

Comment: ya i got that error too. I think its not able to access your file.txt. Location of file.txt?

Comment: String filename = "D:/BPM/SBPM/webapps/deploy/svm/helo/file.txt"; I gave it like this.

Comment: Have you got any luck?

Comment: are you sure there no error in code. I think changing of the file path wont working.

Comment: what is the path name you gave?. what is coming in stack trace access is denied but for what.

Comment: OK I have copied error from `server.logs` and pasted below **[#|2014-01-19T21:22:31.857+0530|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=97;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

Comment: props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com"); Try both of them with gmail account id.

Comment: Ty Referring this for SSL handshake. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore

Comment: now error is reduced. `com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required.` I tried with `properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");` but still not working.

Comment: Its very close now.Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189320/how-to-solve-com-sun-mail-smtp-smtpsendfailedexception-in-java

Comment: no errors but still have exception in console `Interrupting idle Thread: http-thread-pool-8080(1)` I try to search google but didn't got proper solution.

Comment: Size of file.txt? you are attaching is it huge. Its a known issue of glassfish.
Go to glassfish bin. open asadmin console and write this command.
    `asadmin set
server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.request-timeout-seconds=900`

Comment: the text file is only 1 Kb. I tried with above now it create new .log of each each execution process. error is still same `Interrupting idle Thread: http-thread-pool-8080(1)` & `asadmin command not found.`

Comment: Try wrting this in asadmin `set server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.request-tim‌​eout-seconds=900`

Comment: command works but code doesn't, why this happening with me. I want to use it in my project. I think I need to find any other alternative for this.

Comment: I dont think it will create any problem in other application server. which application server does your project use?

Comment: don't know but most probably glassfish. thank you for your great help.

Comment: use this, can help in case of any question https://code.google.com/p/simple-java-mail/